# Almost duplicate - should I ask a new question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

The question [Can not enable 3D acceleration on Ubuntu 14.04 inside VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477738/can-not-enable-3d-acceleration-on-ubuntu-14-04-inside-virtualbox) describes exactly my problem at hand, **except** that it is for VB running under OSX 10.9.3 host for the OP and Win7 host for me.

The one and only answer there wasn't useful (for neither the OP nor myself), so I am wondering if I should start a new question for my Windows 7 host?

Answer (score 2):

Both your issues looks from here like a regression bug (I updated and then things just borked) and has to be addressed by developers. I would recommend you to open a bug report instead of asking a question.

Comment: Thanks. Should I report this bug for Ubuntu or for VirtualBox? And what did you update when it "borked"?

Comment: @FriendFX I would try VB first, since it was the only change you made.

Comment: @FriendFX if I read correctly Braiam didn't mean **he** had upgraded and ...  but he cited **you**.

Comment: @guntbert I didn't update anything. The linked question is by someone else. Anyway the whole issue seems resolved (see my answer there), at least for me. It seems to have been a (now fixed) problem with the Guest Additions.